# How do you organize large Rest APIs with SLIM Microframework?

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

I'm trying to use Slim, but I am not sure if I can grow with a structure like this:

```
$app->group('/robots', function () use ($app) {

    include_once('controller/RobotController.php');

    $controller = new RobotController();

    $app->get('/:id', array($controller, 'getRobot'))
        ->conditions(array('id' => '[0-9]'));
});
```

I just want to have a Controller(skinny) Model(fat) like structure and respond json. But I don't want to have all in a single file, and I don't want to load every Controller I don't need.

**What approach do you have?**

This URL is unfortunately not helpful:
http://www.slimframework.com/2011/09/24/how-to-organize-a-large-slim-framework-application.html

Comment: What version of Slim are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that using $app->group doesn't isolate any statement contained inside it. In your case, the controller will be instantiated no matter if the route matches or not.

Consider this example:

```
$app->group('/group1', function () use ($app) {

    $app->get('/route1', function () use ($app) {
        echo '<br> group1 route1';
    });

    echo '<br>group1';
});

$app->group('/group2', function () use ($app) {
    echo '<br> group2';
});

$app->group('/group3', function () use ($app) {
    echo '<br> group3';
});
```

Requesting `/group1/route1` will output

```
group1
group2
group3
group1 route1
```

In your case, it would be better to organize your folder structure to take advantage of PSR autoloading. If you're already using composer this should be trivial. Then your group would look like

```
$app->group('/robots', function () use ($app) {

    $app->get('/:id', 'controller\RobotController:getRobot')
        ->conditions(array('id' => '[0-9]'));
});
```

if your autoloader know that the namespace 'controller' maps to the 'controller' folder then you don't need to manually include said class.

Please note that I'm using a colon `:` instead of paamayim `::`, because I want Slim to instantiate RobotController and call a non-static method on that instance.

**Clarification**: letting the autoloader "know" means do add a proper mapping, specifying an `autoloader` entry in your `composer.json`. This allows to map a namespace to an arbitrary folder of our convenience

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "controller\\": "src/controllers_folder",
        "model\\": "src/doctrine_models"
    }
},
```

This will delay the instantiation of your controller until you have a matching route.

There are other tricks you can use, such as keeping different route groups in different files, then including just the one that matches the first part of the requested url (in your case, the route would be `robots.php`)

Comment: how do you let the autoloader 'know'?

Comment: Hi @JosephAstrahan, I added a clarification of what I meant. Once you run `composer install` (or `composer dump-autoload`) that mapping will be added to your autoloader.